# Cordova/Android on click/tap/vclick/touchstart not working

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

**NOTE: The following issue only occurs on Android versions above 4.4.2 (as far as I know)**

---

**TL;DR** buttons with click/tap/vclick/touchstart attached to them, seem to work only partly (10-30% of the time) in my cordova app (Android only).

---

I'm trying to develop a hybrid app for ios/android/windows. In the app, I'll have the occasional button that needs to trigger some actions.

Generally I'd use `.on('click', function() { ... });`, but I've learned that `click` doesn't really cooperate with mobile devices.

I tried changing `click` with `vclick`, `tap` and `touchstart`. But nothing seems to trigger my click events.

Next I tried to see if there was perhaps any css blocking my triggers, but nothing consistent.

The issue with this is, when I apply the following piece of code in my console, it would work sometimes (not always):

```
$('.anyElement').on('tap', function(){
  console.log("tapped");
});
```

I also tried the following, because I thought the binding was messed up somehow:

```
$('.anyElement').off().on('tap', function(){
  console.log("tapped");
});
```

So currently I'm kind of not sure where to look anymore. If there perhaps are ways for me to figure out why my stuff doesn't get triggered, that'd be great!

Answer (score 0):

was having the same issue on a cordova jquery app on intel xdk, what solved it for me, at least for now is commenting "fastclick.min.js" in my index.html. seems fastclick.min.js  was the causing the issue on android, as it was working on IOS, check out http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/simple-js-events-like-onclick-are-not-working-on-devices he also soved it by removing some conflicted js, "smoothstate.js" in his case. am still tryin to figure out a better fix though if it exists

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't use the fastclick library. I did however try to check the other libraries and comment them, but nothing changed for me. Here is a quick summary of the libraries I'm using: cordova.js, jquery-1.8.2.min.js, jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js, jquery.event.drag-2.2.js, jquery.mobile.simpledialog2.min.js, jQMProgressBar.js, slick.core.js, slick.grid.js, slick.dataview.js, slick.pager.js, toastr.min.js, moment.min.js, underscore.min.js, data-selector.js and statusbar.js